# Share view of axes in matplotlib: How to link rotation of 3D plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to link the axes’ view of 3D subplots of an interactive plot with *matplotlib*. The code open two [3D scatter plots](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/scatter3d.html) with random numbers. The right subplot should share the x- and y-axis with the one on the left. A property to share the z-axis seems to don't even exist...

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
axs = []
for i in range(2):
    if i == 0:
        ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, i + 1, projection='3d')
    else:
        ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, i + 1, projection='3d', sharex=axs[0], sharey=axs[0])
    axs.append(ax)
    # create data
    x = np.random.rand(100, 1)
    y = np.random.rand(100, 1)
    z = np.random.rand(100, 1)
    # plot (add points to axis)
    ax.scatter(x, y, z)
# draw
plt.show()
```

I used interactive plotting with PyQt5 (simply call `%matplotlib qt` to open [interactive figures](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/interactive.html) in a separate window)
Now, when I rotate a plot, only this one updates the view, but the second plot stays unaffected. However, I was expecting to see both plots being updated in sync because they share axes. I was expecting a similar behavior as MATLAB’s [`linkaxes`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linkaxes.html)-function.

[image]